# How to increase perm size in weblogic

Tags: java, weblogic

I am  using Weblogic 10.3.After doing some work i always get perm gen error.I want to know how to get rid off it. How to increase perm size and up to what limit  we can increase it?

Comment: Why didn't you just google it? It's the first result! https://www.google.com/search?q=weblogic+perm+size

Answer (score 3):

You will have to modify commEnv.sh/commEnv.cmd scripts in `<WL_HOME>/wlserver_10.3/common/bin/`. The argument you're looking for is `-XX:MaxPermSize=256m`

Your perm size is part of the larger heap size so you'd want to allocate it accordingly. There is no absolute rule for its sizing since the requirements vary from application to application. The IBM/Oracle documentation covers this in-depth.

Answer (score 1):

Do the following...

Before editing take a backup of setDomainEnv.cmd or setDomainEnv.sh file

Edit the setDomainEnv.cmd or setDomainEnv.sh file

set the value to as per your application requirement

set USER_MEM_ARGS=-Xmx2048m -XX:PermSize=512m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m